# Best practice for MEF/Prism for this example?

Tags: c#, wcf, prism, mef

I have classes generated from a WCF soap service.

```
public partial class Job
{
  public ActivityId {get;set;}          
}
```

And written additions to the classes

```
public partial class Job
{
  public Activity Activity 
  {
    get
    {
      return *ActivityService*.Activities
                  .Where(x=>x.ActivityId==this.ActivityId)
                  .FirstOrDefault();
    }
  }
}
```

Due to the modular nature of Prism, the classes the list of Activity come from a different web service and module to what Job is generated from.

So what's the best way of populating *ActivityService* or is there a better approach?

Cheers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just to note, I've taken a different approach and used a decorator pattern.

The JobService imports the ActivityService at construction and references it using a private member field. When the JobService retrieves job from the WCF service it populates the Activity using the ActivityService.

```
public class JobService
{
  private ActivityService activityService;

  public JobService(ActivityService activityService)
  {
    this.activityService = activityService;
  }

  public Job GetJob(int jobId)
  {
    using(Client client = new Client())
    {
       Job j = client.GetJob(jobId);

       j.Activity = this.activityService.Activities
                        .Where(a=>a.ActivityId == j.ActivityId)
                        .FirstOrDefault();
       return j;
    }
  }  
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You fix `Export Attribute` on your service , you fix `Import` on your Client, and you finish by register your `Catalog` of services

```
public partial class Job
{
  [Import]
  public Activity Activity 
  {
    get
    {
      return *ActivityService*.Activities
                  .Where(x=>x.ActivityId==this.ActivityId)
                  .FirstOrDefault();
    }
  }
}

[Export]
public class Activity
{
 ...

}
```

Comment: Thanks for your help. In the end I used a decorator pattern instead to populate the activity using the service.

Comment: I'am happy to help you Alxwest